# Ffmpeg-fluent throwing "At least one output file must be specified" error

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Code:

inputs: The directory is my directory. Username is a string, for example "james".
fileExtentionsion is the video extension, for example .mp4.
dateStr is a date string.
Compression is just the factor, ie 40.

```
ffmpeg()
      .input(`${directory}${username}/video${fileExtension}`)
      .save(`${directory}${username}/${dateStr}${fileExtension}`)
      .addOptions(`-c:v libx265 -crf ${compression} -preset veryfast -c:a aac -b:a 128k`)
      .on("start", (commandLine) => {
        console.log("start : " + commandLine);
      })
      .on("progress", (progress) => {
        console.log("In Progress !!" + Date());
      })
      .on("end", () => resolve())
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("reject");
        return reject(err);
      });
  });
```

Does anyone know why this does not run, even though it runs in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `dateStr` variable does not have a "/" (forward slash), as it is not possible to save files with this character.

## Wrong:

```
let dateStr = "10/26/2020"
```

## Right:

```
let dateStr = "26-10-2020"
```

**Let me know if you solved it.**

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your solution was not the issue - my date string already used dashes and not slashes. I ended up solving it by adding the output options as an array, with each option as an element.